# Retrieving user data on facebook PHP SDK v4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm almost at my wits end. I'm not a professional programmer, but I'm trying to work my way here.... I was using the old facebook PHP SDK for my website (around 8 pages that uses fb sdk, login included). However, it just fails to display the user name all of a sudden! It says Uncaught Oauth Error (#100) Unknown fields:name (when i try to display facebook user name from userid stored in db). SO, I UPDATED THE SDK.

And here's the problem. I found some tutorials about this new sdk and i make them work... in a single page. But when i do it like this:

Login.php--->page1.php--->page2.php and so on,

it just doesnt work as well as the old php sdk. I tried saving sessions, but i just can't do it! T_T. It needs to login over and over and over.

So, does anyone know the counterpart for the:

$user->getUser(); in the new SDK4? Thank you very much. At the very least, i just want to make a successful login with facebook and redirect to my main page which displays "welcome $user_name to my blog!"

Thank you very very very much.

EDIT: Here's line 24-38 from the sdk's php file. (from facebook sdk)
(since i'm always getting this error: Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' not found in G:\wamp\FacebookRequestException.php on line 33)

```
namespace Facebook;

/**
 * Class FacebookRequestException
 * @package Facebook
 * @author Fosco Marotto <fjm@fb.com>
 * @author David Poll <depoll@fb.com>
 */
class FacebookRequestException extends FacebookSDKException
{

  /**
   * @var int Status code for the response causing the exception
   */
  private $statusCode;

  /**
   * @var string Raw response
   */
  private $rawResponse;

  /**
   * @var array Decoded response
   */
  private $responseData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your current code it's difficult to point you to the problem.

Have you followed the 'Retrieve User Profile via the Graph API' tutorial? It shows you how to get the basic info, such as the name with `$user_profile->getName()`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/4.0.0

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I don't have a solid code yet because i find it hard to make it work, so i kept on changing and changing. I tried the tutorials and docs but they won't work too. This is the usual error i get:

 Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' not found in *location of sdk.php* on line 33

Thanks for the answer

Comment: You must include the classes/files manually. Have you done that?

Comment: yes sir, i already included the necessary classes and even checked the paths. =( The new sdk doesnt have enough working examples (for not so good developers like me) to replace the old one.

Comment: Can you post the `sdk.php` file, or if it's long the surroundings of line 33 (the whole function if the line is in a function)?

Comment: It seems like you haven't `include`d `FacebookSDKException`.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
```

and

```
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
```

in your page ..

Comment: Or use an autoloader, which is an essential tool when working with classes =3